# I cannot format my flash usb stick - newby user

Tags: usb, flash, format

I have the latest edition of ubuntu, formated my pc 1 week ago.
I Right clicked on the USB flash partition and I sow the format option. It is not grayed out, I do the format, it shows no files when I open the usb file, but when I click on priorities, it shows 94% full.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to unmount the disk before formatting it. You can do this by clicking on the *eject* icon next to drive in Nautilus:

[image: nautilus eject icon]

You can then right-click on the drive to format it. If you still face problems, try using a more [advanced partitioning tool like GParted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted) that will tell you why things aren't working as you expect.

Comment: I will try your second option and see from there, because first one doesn't work for my haunted pc...!